# R SHINY: RUN A FUNCTION, GET A DF AND SHOWS THIS DF AS OUTPUT

Tags: r, function, shiny

estoy intentando desarrollar un programa con shiny, que corra una funcion previamente desarrollada, y que saque uno de los DF que crea la función, y la muestre en la APP desarrollada junto a los parámetros necesarios de entrada que hacen posible que la función en sí corra y devuelva una tabla. Actualmente Shiny no me muestra dicha tabla, tampoco me da error. Adjunto cODE a continuación.

```
library(shiny)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session){ function(n_copias =input$des_copias, costes_arranque=input$des_Costes_Arranque, ancho=input$des_ancho_formato, alto=input$des_alto_formato, porcentaje_tinta=100, 
           Destino='P', papel=input$DES_PAPEL, caras=input$des_Caras, color=input$DES_COLOR, plastificado=input$des_plastificado, 
           caras_plastificadas=caras, hendido=input$des_hendido, plegado=input$des_plegado, esquinas=input$des_esquinas, 
           agujeros=input$des_, troquelado = input$des_troquelado, beneficio=input$des_beneficio, peso=input$des_peso, n_paquetes=input$des_paquetes) {
    #se calcula el modelo para el numero de copias originles, mas otros posibles escenarios.
    copias_vector = c(n_copias, n_copias*2.5, n_copias*5, n_copias*10)
    #se calcula el ancho real y el largo real, por que hay que respetar los margenes de impresion y los cortes
    ancho_real = ancho + 0.05
    alto_real = alto + 0.05
    #ya podemos sabes cuantas uds caben por pliego.
    uds_pliego = round(32/ancho_real, 0) * round(45/alto_real, 0)
    #calculamos los costes unitarios
    coste_papel_unit_df=subset(data_papel, DES_PAPEL == papel)
    coste_papel_unit = coste_papel_unit_df$COSTE_UNIT
    coste_color_unit_df=subset(data_color, DES_COLOR == color)
    coste_color_unit = coste_color_unit_df$COSTE_UNIT
    coste_plastificado_unit_df=subset(data_plastificado, DES_PLASTIFICADO == plastificado)
    coste_plastificado_unit = coste_plastificado_unit_df$COSTE_UNIT
    coste_hendido_unit_df=subset(data_hendido, COD_HENDIDO == hendido)
    coste_hendido_unit = coste_hendido_unit_df$COSTE_UNIT
    coste_plegado_unit_df=subset(data_hendido, COD_HENDIDO == plegado)
    coste_plegado_unit = coste_plegado_unit_df$COSTE_UNIT
    coste_esquinas_unit_df=subset(data_hendido, COD_HENDIDO == esquinas)
    coste_esquinas_unit = coste_esquinas_unit_df$COSTE_UNIT
    coste_agujeros_unit_df=subset(data_hendido, COD_HENDIDO == agujeros)
    coste_agujeros_unit = coste_agujeros_unit_df$COSTE_UNIT
    coste_troquelado_unit_df=subset(data_troquelado, DES_TROQUELADO == troquelado)
    coste_troquelado_unit = coste_troquelado_unit_df$COSTE_UNIT
    total_pliegos= trunc(copias_vector/uds_pliego) + 4 #siempre se necesitan 3 pliegos de margen + 1 de redondeo hacia arriba
    #Coste de Papel
    Coste_Papel = coste_papel_unit*total_pliegos
    Coste_impresion = coste_color_unit*total_pliegos*caras
    Coste_plastificado = coste_plastificado_unit*total_pliegos*caras_plastificadas
    Coste_troquelado=coste_troquelado_unit*total_pliegos
    millares = round(total_pliegos/1000, 0)+1
    Coste_hendido_full_unit=coste_hendido_unit+coste_plegado_unit+coste_esquinas_unit+coste_agujeros_unit
    coste_hendido_full = Coste_hendido_full_unit*millares
    Coste_final_unit=Coste_Papel+Coste_impresion+Coste_plastificado+Coste_troquelado+coste_hendido_full
    pvp=(Coste_final_unit+costes_arranque) * (1+beneficio)
    table33 <- reactive({as.data.frame(cbind(copias_vector, pvp), c("COPIAS","PVP"))})
    return(table33)
    plots.dfs <- eventReactive(input$button, {return(table33())})
    output$table <- renderTable(head(table33()))
    
  }}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y colocar el título en castellano? Saludos

Comment: Hola Felipe, el código que compartes esta alejado de ser una shiny app funcional. Te falta definir el UI. Te sugiero que definas la funcioón que genera la tabla fuera del server y la llames en el evento reactivo.